# List mapping in Play2's form

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a form with multiple textarea, each goes with a corresponding checkbox. Basically, the application works as "If yes (the checkbox is checked), leave the textarea blank. Otherwise, fill in your explanation on why do you think it's wrong".

In models, I have

```
case class AnswerMapping(id: Long, status: Option[String], result: Option[String]

val form = Form[Seq[Answers](
  mapping(
   "details" ->
      list(mapping(
        "id" -> longNumber,
        "status" -> optional(text),
        "result" -> optional(text)
      )(AnswerMapping.apply)(AnswerMapping.unapply)
  ))(apply)(unapply)
)
```

In views, I have

```
@helper.form(action = controllers.conflict.routes.Answer.updateAnswer(ans.id()) {
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      @ans.details.get.zipWithIndex.map { case(detail, index) =>
        @helper.textarea(
          form(("details[" + index + "].result")),
          'class -> "input-xlarge resizable",
          'id -> ("box" + index),
          '_label -> "")
      }
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <input value="Submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

The rendered HTML looks like `<textarea id="box0" name="details[0].result" class="input-xlarge resizable" id="box0"></textarea>`

However, when I submitted the form, I was redirected back to the same page. This is probably because I have this in my controllers, which means there's error in my form

```
Ans.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => Ok(views.html.answer.edit(answer, formWithErrors)),
  ans => { // save the answer }
```

My question:

1. Is the above, `details[0].result` the right syntax to access an element in a form's list
2. I don't quite understand why my form has errors. The two fields that needs to be filled in are marked as optional, simply because sometimes a checkbox is not checked, and sometimes the answer box is left blank. Is this perhaps because of the id field? I already set it in my apply/unapply method, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks for all the input.

Comment: How your `Answers.class` code looks like? Are you tried to write a test for your form submission? Are you tried to handle form errors, if so, what you get?

Comment: I don't know Scala but where in the form do you pass the `id` to the controller? I don't see any `<input name="id" type="..."/>` in the form. If you don't pass it, the form will have an error because it's not `optional` in your form. (even though you seem to be directly passing it to the controller method, I could be wrong but I don't think it works like that)

Comment: As for your first question, yes that looks correct.

Comment: Thanks arussinov and Aerus. It was indeed the id. Phew! I think I kinda got it now, but I will ask more questions if somethings comes up.

Answer (score 0):

see document:[Repeated values](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms)

```
@helper.repeat(myForm("emails"), min = 1) { emailField =>
    @helper.inputText(emailField)
}
```